# #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server - After running an Acunetix scan

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I know this type of question has been asked lots of times, but none answer my problem. 
Please read carefully.

I was running my website on localhost using Wamp server normally. When today i decided to run an Acunetix scan for vulnerabilities on my localhost server.

Acunetix sent tons of commands to the mysql table in short period of time ( since it's localhost the commands went fast ) which cause my mysql server to crash with the error:

```
#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

**What I've already tried:**

Running mysql through  mysqld --skip-grant-tables
I had access to mysql while on that, so I tried running

```
DROP USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%';
```

But I got the error:

```
mysql> DROP USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%';
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables opt
ion so it cannot execute this statement
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO 'r
oot'@'%'' at line 1
```

I admit I do am a mysql noob but I did my homeworks and searched google, but was unable to find the solution.

Any help ?

I managed ti fix the issue by reinstalling wamp server and fully uninstalling, even with the mysql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your server is running with --skip-grant-tables, you disable all MySQL security so you're not allowed GRANT commands. What you can do, is access the "mysql" database and directly SELECT and UPDATE the rows you need to change. In your case it will be the user table.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. 
Since Phpmyadmin is not working, can you please give me the query for that ? What should I update ?

Comment: If I understand correctly your need, you should try this: use mysql; update user set Host='%' where User='root' and Host='127.0.0.1'; flush privileges;   but I'm not sure whether the "flush privileges" will work; if not, just restart your MySQL server after the "update" statement.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to recreate your privilege tables, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db-problems.html

Comment: Well I managed to fix it by reinstalling wampserver.
Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @MarcDelisle, If access to `grant` is not allowed, how could access to the underlying `mysql` tables be allowed? Isn't that totally oxymoronic?

Comment: @Pacerier From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html : "Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges."

Comment: @MarcDelisle, Yes I mean what's the point of disabling the `grant` command since the underlying access is allowed?

Comment: @Pacerier A good question for the MySQL team. Maybe they want to make you realize that you are running without any privilege system active.

Comment: @MarcDelisle, If that's the case you would get a warning instead of an access deny.

Comment: @Pacerier well you might want to tell that to the MySQL team.

Answer (score 36):

### A simple Illustrated solution!

[image]

Comment: this started happening after updating windows OS. And, followed above steps to resolve.

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.

You can add `skip-grant-tables` to the my.ini file for the `[mysqld]` tag, under `# The MySQL server`, and restart the mysql server.

You can now open phpmyadmin and go to the user table in the mysql database. Make sure that the value of the password attribute is empty and that the value of host attribute is localhost. I was facing the second error. PHPMyAdmin was trying to connect with host value as 'localhost' and the table contained the value 127.0.0.1.

Remove skip-grant-tables from my.ini and restart the mysql server. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
     GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

EDIT.

this because your mysql server is on read_only option.  to turn it off

connect to the server with root user:

```
mysql-h localhost-u root-p
```

and run the command:

```
mysql> set GLOBAL read_only = false;

mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

EDIT2;

you must have stop the server and run this

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`   due to root pwd chg

so stop the server and start it normal with a start

Comment: I also can't use that. I got the error:ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables opt
ion so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. But unfortunately It's still not working.
This is what I done:http://pastebin.com/aqFjcrzX

Comment: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin>mysqld_safe
'mysqld_safe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: use this `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` instead

Comment: be sure to stop mysql before running this code , and then start it again

Comment: That's what I've been using the whole time.
I only have access to the mysql database when my server is running with mysqld --skip-grant-tables. I did stopped the mysql.

Comment: Thanks mate for helping me.
I managed to fix it by reinstalling WampServer.

Comment: Most of answers are without reading the question. If you can't login in mysql then where to execute query? In my friend's computer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on **config** show in image
2. Click **my.ini** show in image
3. add **skip-grant-tables** after [mysqld] and save show in image. (*edited spelling issue here)
4. Now restart **mySQL**. that's all

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by reinstalling the server.
The new configuration (`my.ini`) does not contain the `--skip-grant-tables` option and I am able to connect to the server as expected.

Don't forget to backup your databases before you do the new installation.